# Manually create dummy based on some condition, what went wrong?

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have a dataset that has a column of numbers and NaNs. I want to create a new column of dummy variables for further calculation. Apparently something is wrong, because whatever I do the dummy will be 1.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
all_air = pd.read_csv('small.csv')

all_air['D(0/1)']=np.nan
#all_air['C'].fillna(-1) #pandas will take NaN as 0 in calculation, right?
print all_air['C']


for n in all_air['C']:
    if n is None:
        all_air['D(0/1)'] = 0
    else:
        all_air['D(0/1)'] = 1
all_air.to_csv('sample_small.csv')
```

I am new to python, so this is as far as I can get to.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment operation

```
all_air['D(0/1)'] = 0
```

sets the value to `0` for the entire column named `'D(0/1)'`. So in effect, each time you encounter a value of `n` where `n is None`, you set *the whole column* to 0. Likewise, when `n is not None` you set *the whole column* to `1`.

It seems from your description that you would rather have a mask, those locations where `n is None` for example, and only modify values at *those* locations.

This can be achieved with the `loc` indexer:

```
all_air['D(0/1)'] = 1
all_air.loc[all_air['C'].isnull(), 'D(0/1)'] = 0
```

In this example, I made use of the built-in function `isnull` that can check all the elements of a `pandas.Series` to see if they are null (`NaN` or `None`). It returns a `pandas.Series` of Boolean values. Those locations which evaluate to `True` will be considered part of the index for evaluation.

So by passing this as the first dimension of the index for `loc`, we can modify the values in only those rows. The second dimension identifies the column to modify. Putting the value of `0` on the right-hand-side will automatically broadcast that scalar into a compatible array shape for assigning it into the column (some `K`-by-`1` column vector, where `K` will be the number of null entries).

Comment: I understand the first half of your answer(before loc). So I should add this before the for loop, right?

Comment: The for-loop is unnecessary (and in fact, inefficient). In general, in the Python scientific stack, you want to avoid for-loops in favor of operations that can be directly applied to arrays and handle their array-ness in the expected way.